# User activity log in Apache Kafka, and GDPR delete requests

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm planning on using Apache Kafka to handle user activity from a number of different services. The idea is, each service would send messages that look like this:

```
key: "u001", message: `{type:"account-modify", details:{...}}`
key: "u002", message: `{type:"account-modify", details:{...}}`
key: "u001", message: `{type:"document-create", details:{...}}`
key: "u001", message: `{type:"comment-added", details:{...}}`
key: "u001", message: `{type:"comment-added", details:{...}}`
```

The keys here are the user IDs in my database, and the messages would have a "type" (activity type), a timestamp, and some data that would change according to the type.

Then, I'd have consumers reading all this data and producing different things, one of which would be a nice user-friendly activity log with a different structure from the one above (maybe I don't want to include every time a user adds a comment but show a single "user added 5 comments" message, and maybe I don't care about certain types for this user-facing log). This consumer would write to a regular DB so that the app would read from there and show the user-friendly data as a HTML table.

At this point I have a simple question: **Am I crazy to use Kafka for this?** The reasons I chose it are:

- Scalability. The system is already pretty large, so it's nice to be able to have a managed Kafka installation (probably using the Amazon service) that's reliable and scalable and available and all that, and the concept of consumer groups where I can spin up as many instances of the thing building the user-facing activity log as needed.
- Separation. It's desirable to have the producer/consumer architecture where producers can just send messages without having to wait for consumers to produce the data (e.g. the user-facing activity log).

Now, there are some concerns. I've been reading about how GDPR deletion requests can be handled in Kafka, and it seems when you send a "tombstone" message for a key, it will delete all the messages with that key. However, this seems to require a "compact cleanup policy", and I'm not sure exactly what this means. From the documentation, it seems like "compact" means Kafka will regularly delete every message from every key except the most recent one for the key. **Is this true? and, can I use a "tombstone" message to delete all the activity logged by a single user in my system, but keep the separate messages (i.e. my activity log) intact?**

Finally, and risking *really* making this a long question, **is this a good design for my system? is Kafka a good match for what I need?**

Comment: Any follow-up on this? I think GDPR is one of the things that makes using Kafka sound like a pain.

Comment: P.S. Have you read [this post about GDPR](https://www.confluent.io/blog/handling-gdpr-log-forget)? It seems to add more detail about compacted topics.